# Ubuntu VSFTPD stopped working out of the blue, nothing changed

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

So via Ubuntu11x, out of no where I can't write into any files via VSFTPD.

It doesn't make sense, nothings been changed; it's been working fine for about 6 months now.  The only error code I get (i.e. making directory) is 550 operation failed.

Literally, nothing was changed with anything, it just flipped on it's own.

Comment: How are the rights in the folder structure you are trying to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, MongoDB ate up 100% of my memory.  So the system had zero space for cache.

So I removed some old archives and wal-ah.